# Looking for a Java based SCSS to CSS Converter

Tags: java, css, sass, jawr

I'm looking for a Java based SCSS to CSS Converter to write a [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) Preprocessor for this.
So it's important to keep comments for [building Sprites with Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/tutorials/jawrSpriteImage.html).

I just found [SAC](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/) which seems to be a great base start writing one.

CSS Level 3 has to be supported - that's why [CSS Parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) isn't a choice.

If I have to write my own (which will be Open Source and hosted on [GitHub](http://github.com/) for sure):
Is there any SCSS Parser? If not, can I write my own based on SAC as well?
Would anyone help me?

**EDIT** I just saw there's also a [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) Syntax which looks much better to me than SCSS. Alternatively or in addition to SCSS, LESS would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this awesome project: [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/)

EDIT: For Completeness: Jawr will implement these features in their next release as well.